# JavaScript is Object or Function

Tags: javascript, object

I have this code:

```
var obj = function (i) {
   this.a = i;
   this.init = function () {
       var _this = this;
       setTimeout(function () {
           alert(_this.a + ' :: ' + typeof _this);
       }, 0);
   };
   this.init();
};

obj('1');
obj('2');
obj('3');
new obj('4');​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kbWJd/

The script alerts '3 :: object' three times and '4 :: object' once.

I know why this is. It because `new obj('4')` creates a new instance with it's own memory space and the calls prior share their memory space. When in the code of `obj` how can I determine if I am a new object or a function, since `typeof _this` just says 'object'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? If you execute a function without the `new` keyword `this` inside the function equals the containing object (`window` in this case).

```
if( this === window ){
    console.log('not an object instance');
} else {
    console.log('object instance');
}
```

Example with different containing object:

```
var obj = {

    method: function(){

        if( this === obj ){
            alert('function was not used to create an object instance');
        } else {
            alert('function was used to create an object instance');
        }

    }

};


obj.method(); // this === obj

new obj.method(); // this === newly created object instance
```

Comment: Wouldn't this method require that you know *inside* the function what context it's being called in?

Comment: @sam Not sure I understand. The if statement determines the context.

Comment: I suppose it works if you create it as `var obj = ` - however, if you declare it as a named function, you won't be able to use that comparison; eg. `function obj() {}`

Comment: The first example works perfectly inside a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The `instanceof` operator can be utilized for another solution:

```
var foo = function() {
    if (this instanceof foo) {
        // new operator has been used (most likely)
    } else {
        // ...
    }
};
```